# Figwheel not hot reloading or updating on file save when using vagrant

Tags: vagrant, clojurescript, luminus, figwheel

When running figwheel from with a vagrant box it seems that file changes aren't noticed and as a result figwheel does not update/reload the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spending hours trying to figure out what was going on it eventually came down to how figwheel detects file changes.

To detect file changes figwheel uses the [hawk library](https://github.com/wkf/hawk) which in turn uses the operating system to that tell hawk the file has updated. Because vagrant defaults to using vboxsf there is no underlying update mechanism to provide updates that the file has changed, see [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10660). To fix this we just need to tell figwheel, and thus hawk, to poll for file changes:

```
:figwheel {:hawk-options {:watcher :polling}
```

Just pop this in the your profile.clj and that will allow figwheel to see changes after the file has been saved, although it does take a while for the polling to pick up the changes so wait a little bit.

This only however solves half of the problem because figwheel still requires an active websocket connection to actually push the code changes. This is complicated by the fact the a vagrant vm is a separate machine on the network and requires you expose this websocket to more than just localhost. This can be achieved by adding another key to the `figwheel` map in `project.clj`:

```
:figwheel {:server-ip "0.0.0.0"}
```

and then exposing the figwheel websocket port in the vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3449, host: 3449
```

and that should fix figwheel on vagrant!

Answer (score 1):

FYI had a similar problem and work on the following solution

[troubleshooting on vagrant docker](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot/wiki/Boot-Troubleshooting#watch-task-not-working-in-docker--vagrant)

to quote

> Watch Task not working in Docker / Vagrant?
>
> Scenario: Changes made to a file mounted with Docker / Vagrant between
>   the guest and host os via NFS; filesystem events are not received
>   correctly.
>
> Resolution: Use rsync in these environments, as NFS does not support
>   inotify. You may also wish to run a repl server in the guest os and
>   connect to it from the host.

Comment: I had trouble getting rsync to function properly on windows but this is also a valid solution as far I could tell

Comment: there was some issue with windows however there was some workarounds specifically for windows in that arena